# Video Recording on Android from Frames using javaCV

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv

I am using this library [javaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) to record video on android. They have provided a sample VideoRecording Activity But There is some bug which I could not figure out what I am doing it wrong or what is missing which causing this bug.

```
package org.bytedeco.javacv.recordactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;

public class RecordActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private final static String CLASS_LABEL = "RecordActivity";
    private final static String LOG_TAG = CLASS_LABEL;

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    private String ffmpeg_link = "/mnt/sdcard/stream.flv";

    long startTime = 0;
    boolean recording = false;

    private volatile FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;

    private boolean isPreviewOn = false;

    private int sampleAudioRateInHz = 44100;
    private int imageWidth = 320;
    private int imageHeight = 240;
    private int frameRate = 30;

    /* audio data getting thread */
    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private AudioRecordRunnable audioRecordRunnable;
    private Thread audioThread;
    volatile boolean runAudioThread = true;

    /* video data getting thread */
    private Camera cameraDevice;
    private CameraView cameraView;

    private IplImage yuvIplimage = null;

    /* layout setting */
    private final int bg_screen_bx = 232;
    private final int bg_screen_by = 128;
    private final int bg_screen_width = 700;
    private final int bg_screen_height = 500;
    private final int bg_width = 1123;
    private final int bg_height = 715;
    private final int live_width = 640;
    private final int live_height = 480;
    private int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    private Button btnRecorderControl;

    /** The number of seconds in the continuous record loop (or 0 to disable loop). */
    final int RECORD_LENGTH = 10;
    IplImage[] images;
    long[] timestamps;
    ShortBuffer[] samples;
    int imagesIndex, samplesIndex;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, CLASS_LABEL); 
        mWakeLock.acquire(); 

        initLayout();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mWakeLock == null) {
           PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
           mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, CLASS_LABEL);
           mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        recording = false;

        if (cameraView != null) {
            cameraView.stopPreview();
        }

        if(cameraDevice != null) {
           cameraDevice.stopPreview();
           cameraDevice.release();
           cameraDevice = null;
        }

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }


    private void initLayout() {

        /* get size of screen */
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = null; 
        LayoutInflater myInflate = null; 
        myInflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout topLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(topLayout);
        LinearLayout preViewLayout = (LinearLayout) myInflate.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        topLayout.addView(preViewLayout, layoutParam);

        /* add control button: start and stop */
        btnRecorderControl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recorder_control);
        btnRecorderControl.setText("Start");
        btnRecorderControl.setOnClickListener(this);

        /* add camera view */
        int display_width_d = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_width * screenWidth / bg_width);
        int display_height_d = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_height * screenHeight / bg_height);
        int prev_rw, prev_rh;
        if (1.0 * display_width_d / display_height_d > 1.0 * live_width / live_height) {
            prev_rh = display_height_d;
            prev_rw = (int) (1.0 * display_height_d * live_width / live_height);
        } else {
            prev_rw = display_width_d;
            prev_rh = (int) (1.0 * display_width_d * live_height / live_width);
        }
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(prev_rw, prev_rh);
        layoutParam.topMargin = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_by * screenHeight / bg_height);
        layoutParam.leftMargin = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_bx * screenWidth / bg_width);

        cameraDevice = Camera.open();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cameara open");
        cameraView = new CameraView(this, cameraDevice);
        topLayout.addView(cameraView, layoutParam);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cameara preview start: OK");
    }

    //---------------------------------------
    // initialize ffmpeg_recorder
    //---------------------------------------
    private void initRecorder() {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG,"init recorder");

        if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
            imagesIndex = 0;
            images = new IplImage[RECORD_LENGTH * frameRate];
            timestamps = new long[images.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                images[i] = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
                timestamps[i] = -1;
            }
        } else if (yuvIplimage == null) {
            yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "create yuvIplimage");
        }

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + ffmpeg_link);
        recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, imageWidth, imageHeight, 1);
        recorder.setFormat("flv");
        recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
        // Set in the surface changed method
        recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "recorder initialize success");

        audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
        audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
        runAudioThread = true;
    }

    public void startRecording() {

        initRecorder();

        try {
            recorder.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recording = true;
            audioThread.start();

        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {

        runAudioThread = false;
        try {
            audioThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        audioRecordRunnable = null;
        audioThread = null;

        if (recorder != null && recording) {
            if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing frames");
                try {
                    int firstIndex = imagesIndex % samples.length;
                    int lastIndex = (imagesIndex - 1) % images.length;
                    if (imagesIndex <= images.length) {
                        firstIndex = 0;
                        lastIndex = imagesIndex - 1;
                    }
                    if ((startTime = timestamps[lastIndex] - RECORD_LENGTH * 1000000L) < 0) {
                        startTime = 0;
                    }
                    if (lastIndex < firstIndex) {
                        lastIndex += images.length;
                    }
                    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                        long t = timestamps[i % timestamps.length] - startTime;
                        if (t >= 0) {
                            if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                                recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                            }
                            recorder.record(images[i % images.length]);
                        }
                    }

                    firstIndex = samplesIndex % samples.length;
                    lastIndex = (samplesIndex - 1) % samples.length;
                    if (samplesIndex <= samples.length) {
                        firstIndex = 0;
                        lastIndex = samplesIndex - 1;
                    }
                    if (lastIndex < firstIndex) {
                        lastIndex += samples.length;
                    }
                    for (int i = firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
                        recorder.record(samples[i % samples.length]);
                    }
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            recording = false;
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (recording) {
                stopRecording();
            }

            finish();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    //---------------------------------------------
    // audio thread, gets and encodes audio data
    //---------------------------------------------
    class AudioRecordRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            // Audio
            int bufferSize;
            ShortBuffer audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioRateInHz, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleAudioRateInHz, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

            if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
                samplesIndex = 0;
                samples = new ShortBuffer[RECORD_LENGTH * sampleAudioRateInHz * 2 / bufferSize + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
                    samples[i] = ShortBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
                }
            } else {
                audioData = ShortBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            /* ffmpeg_audio encoding loop */
            while (runAudioThread) {
                if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
                    audioData = samples[samplesIndex++ % samples.length];
                    audioData.position(0).limit(0);
                }
                //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording? " + recording);
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData.array(), 0, audioData.capacity());
                audioData.limit(bufferReadResult);
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"bufferReadResult: " + bufferReadResult);
                    // If "recording" isn't true when start this thread, it never get's set according to this if statement...!!!
                    // Why?  Good question...
                    if (recording) {
                        if (RECORD_LENGTH <= 0) try {
                            recorder.record(audioData);
                            //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording " + 1024*i + " to " + 1024*i+1024);
                        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"AudioThread Finished, release audioRecord");

            /* encoding finish, release recorder */
            if (audioRecord != null) {
                audioRecord.stop();
                audioRecord.release();
                audioRecord = null;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"audioRecord released");
            }
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // camera thread, gets and encodes video data
    //---------------------------------------------
    class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, PreviewCallback {

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            Log.w("camera","camera view");
            mCamera = camera;
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(CameraView.this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(CameraView.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Setting imageWidth: " + imageWidth + " imageHeight: " + imageHeight + " frameRate: " + frameRate);
            Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Preview Framerate: " + camParams.getPreviewFrameRate());

            camParams.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
            mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mHolder.addCallback(null);
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // The camera has probably just been released, ignore.
            }
        }

        public void startPreview() {
            if (!isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
                isPreviewOn = true;
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }

        public void stopPreview() {
            if (isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
                isPreviewOn = false;
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (audioRecord == null || audioRecord.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                return;
            }
            if (RECORD_LENGTH > 0) {
                int i = imagesIndex++ % images.length;
                yuvIplimage = images[i];
                timestamps[i] = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            }
            /* get video data */
            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
                yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

                if (RECORD_LENGTH <= 0) try {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Writing Frame");
                    long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                        recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                    }
                    recorder.record(yuvIplimage);
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recording) {
            startRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Start Button Pushed");
            btnRecorderControl.setText("Stop");
        } else {
            // This will trigger the audio recording loop to stop and then set isRecorderStart = false;
            stopRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Stop Button Pushed");
            btnRecorderControl.setText("Start");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

The type org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil$AVFrame cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

at following line in the above code

```
if (RECORD_LENGTH <= 0) try {
    recorder.record(audioData);
    //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording " + 1024*i + " to " + 1024*i+1024);
 }
```

at recorder.record(audioData). I don't know what I am doing wrong here. New to JavaCV. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you included all neccessary .*jar files?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that a jar containing the class `org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil$AVFrame` cannot be found in the java class path. I would suggest to check the class path, the version of `javacv` used, maybe there were bugs that are now solved, you never know. Actually there are some similar discussions on javacv's github account, which may or may not be connected to your problem: [javacv github](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/133), [javacv github](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/137).

What makes me wonder is why you are putting your class in "org.bytedeco.javacv.recordactivity" package? "org.bytedeco.javacv" is javacv's own package, you just don't put your own class into the package structure that do not belong to you. It can only make you troubles in the future, for instance if `javacv` at some time decides to create package and class with the same name.